# merge two columns into a third giving an error

Tags: pandas

I have a `merger` data frame as follows:

```
        Type_x                         Type_y
0          NaN                           val0
1          NaN                           val0
2         val1                            NaN
..         ...                            ...
953        NaN                           val2
954        NaN                            NaN
```

I am trying to use the line `merger['Type'] = merger.stack().values` to blend the lines into one another to achieve this result:

```
        Type_x                         Type_y                           Type
0          NaN                           val0                           val0
1          NaN                           val0                           val0
2         val1                            NaN                           val1
..         ...                            ...                            ...
953        NaN                           val2                           val2
954        NaN                            NaN                            NaN
```

However, it is not working and I get the error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`. However, the two columns appear the same length when I `print(merger)` them out. Also, when I load them up in Excel (replacing the NaNs with 0s) they are the same length.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I had the same issue a few days ago with a different problem, what worked for me was replacing all NaN's with blank space. df1 = df.replace('NaN', '')

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice, I don't think so, because I replaced them all with a 0 and tried it then and it still didn't work. But Mohamed's answer worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood your example I tried this,
It may help you to get your desired result,

```
merger['Type']=merger['Type_x'].copy()
merger['Type']=merger['Type'].fillna(merger['Type_y'])
```